# DataGridView row header cell text visibility

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` in my `WinForms` application. Basically, I want to input some 2D data there or something like that. It means, that I want to have both columns named and rows named. And so I did. But then there was a problem. When it's fine with column names, the row names tend to be not visible. For example:

[image]

The code I use to somehow "beautify" the `DataGridView`:

```
private void BeautifyTable(TableView tableView)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tableView.Rows)
    {
        row.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tableView.Columns)
    {
        col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        col.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    }
}
```

`TableView` is a class created by me, and it inherits from `DataGridView`.

So now my question would be: Is there a way to somehow make those row names/titles appear in a normal way (in this particular case those are: `s0, s1, s2..`, but they're like cut from the left side).

P.S Is there a good way to "stretch" the columns? I mean if I have f.e 10 columns they would fill the whole `DataGridView` width, but if I would add (I do this dynamically) 5, so there would be 15 columns, still they would fit, just the width of every column would decrease?

Comment: What's that arrow in first column? Doesn't that hide the cell beneath it?

Comment: About your PS, try simply set a Width of the GridView.

Comment: Maybe it does. I think it indicates the row, in which the user has selected some cell. Or the whole row

Comment: I don't want to change the width I guess

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of the row header:

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 
    dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth * 2; // or another value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide those arrows by setting the RowHeadersVisible to False in the properties of the datagridview at the Form.cs [Design] or just simply add the code below.

```
Me.DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the best answer by myself.

You can set the `WitdthSizeMode` also for row headers, like this:

```
tableView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
```

And that's the result:

[image]